# Killing activity which starts other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I am creating android application to lock the apps installed in the mobile. In this application, I have created two activities and two classes

1. LockAppMainActivity (Main Activity used for setting password and starting service)
2. CreatedWith (Class file locks the screen after certain time)
3. LockScreen  (Lock screen is shown to the user when user starts app in which lock is applied)
4. ServiceRestarts (Class File to start the service after reboot)

The problem with this application is that when user tries to unlock the app, after unlocking the app the lockscreen goes to background and does not get killed. I want lockscreen activity to get killed when user unlocks the app.

LockAppMainActivity (It starts the service)

```
 startService(new Intent(this, CreatedWith.class));
```

CreatedWith

```
     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId,int ff) {
     int delay = 10;
     int period = 100;
     Timer timer = new Timer(); 
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
         { 
             public void run() 
             { 
                  odopo();  

             } 
         }, delay, period); 

     return START_STICKY;

     }

      void odopo(){

      ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
                if(activityOnTop.contains("whatsapp"))
                {
                    if(LockAppMainActivity.myId!=1){

                Intent lockIntent = new Intent(this, LockScreen.class);
                lockIntent.putExtra("sec", activityOnTop);
                lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                this.startActivity(lockIntent);
                }}}
```

LockScreen
If password entered by the user is correct then the following code runs.

```
             Intent LaunchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(ar.topActivity.getPackageName());
            LaunchApp.setFlags(LaunchApp.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); 
            startActivity(LaunchApp);
```

The problem with this code is that when the application is unlocked the LockScreen goes to background but I want it to get killed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried calling finish()?

Comment: try setting android:noHistory="true" on the activity in your manifest, it will remove an activity from the stack whenever it is navigated away from

Comment: I have already tried that

Comment: Rohit what is this variable: LockAppMainActivity.myId?

Comment: this variable is set to 1 when user unlocks the app, so as to deactivate the lock after user unlocks it with password.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Don't forget to call finish();

If you want to kill it because of the memory usage, you might want to let the OS to kill it.
Android RAM is optimized to stay loaded more than is to stay empty. If the OS reach "out of memory state"(OOM), it begins to kill the lowest priority processes(background processes have very low priorities)